# Hiding two GET METHOD in url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website example.com and I am passing two GET parameters in the url.

```
example.com/page.php?page=5&section=10
```

Now I want it to show

```
example.com/5/10
```

I've already got it to work for the first part but cannot seem to figure out the second part (section part)

My current .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

All I need to get is the second part working (&section=10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect and rewrite the single get perm /?page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

#redirect and rewrite urls with multiple perms   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?page=(\d+)&section=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ page.php?page=$1&section=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This works perfectly but only when I use both the parameters at the same time. However, what I want is to use either the first parameter alone, or use the first and second together (not use the second parameter alone) That is, either use `?page=5&section=10` or use `?page=5`. Now how do I do that? Should've clarified it in the main post. Sorry!

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.+)&section=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
```

This grabs the variables using `{QUERY_STRING}` and rewrites your URL to `http://example.com/5/10`. The use of the `?` on the end of the rewrite is to stop the query from appending onto the end after the rewrite.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it :)